# What is the symbolism behind Ganga flowing from Lord Shiva's head?

Tags: shiva, symbolism, ganga

Images depict *Ganga* flowing out from *Lord Shiva's* head.
What is the symbolism behind this?

**Images:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Ganges is known for its purity. Here is one interpretation: It symbolizes the awakening of the Crown. According to Yogis, there are seven main centers in the body. Final liberation involves awakening of the Center in the Crown. This is called Sahasrara. Upon awakening, the Yogi is One with the Self, thereby becoming the source (or reservoir, if you believe the Ganges is flowing into Lord Shiva's hair) of Purity (Ganges). The beautiful form of Lord Shiva is full of Yogic symbolism! :)

Comment: @Sai Thanks, that is an interesting interpretation. Also, I have noticed that people love to post comments when the same can be posted as a valid answer.

Comment: Also visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva#Attributes

Comment: @Sai Thx for posting that comment, is wonderful 

Answer (score 3):

When Ganga was to decend on Earth it had such a vigorous flow that it could destroy the Earth. So Shiva locked her up in his hair and controlled it's flow to save the Mother Earth.
 So one symbolism is Anything that is turbulent, uncontrollable, that can be brought under control by the Great Lord , every restless being becomes peaceful ,calm and tranquil under his wings. He is the Lord who can channelise tremendous energy in the right constructive path. 
2) The holy Ganges represents purity. So Lord Shiva is the source of all purity that exists on Eearth. He absorbs all the negativety and lets purity flops everything . 
OM NAMAH SHIVAY ....